# Разделить большое целое число на большое целое число, умножить обратно, и получить исходное число

Tags: python, python-2.x, float, python-2.7

Перед прочтением, не торопитесь закидывать ссылками на теорию - помогите практически решить проблему с реальным методом
Имеется целое число `a`, которое нужно разделить на другое целое `b` и получить дробь `c`. Затем обратным преобразованием дробь `c` умножить на делитель `b` и получить делимое `a`.

Пример: число `8993229949524469768` разделить на `63` в `11` степени (`62050608388552823487` если быть точным) и полученный результат умножить на `63` в `11` степени. Вот только питон выдаёт следующий результат `8993229949524469572`. Ещё ни разу не получилось вернуть любому другому числу исходный вид.

Если делить целое на целое, то получим целое. В данном случае `a/b = 0`. Значит либо одно из чисел, прописав в переменные, задать дробным форматом `a = 1.0` или дать тип данных `a = float(89....)`

Проблема номер 2: если число сразу привести к виду
`a=float(8993229949524469768)`, то оно уже автоматом на `print (a)` будет показывать другой результат (`8993229949524469760`). Вроде как число хоть и длинное, но в диапазон вещественных попадает. Не должно меняться.
Что делать? Как дальше жить? Калькулятор на win7 помогал создавать алгоритм на основе примера, но на практике python рушит все надежды и мечты.
Помогите.

Comment: Я голосую за переоткрытие, т.к. в других вопросах речь изначально идет о float типе. Тут же у автора изначально целые и ему нужны точные вычисления с дробями, что отлично можно сделать с помощью модуля `fractions`. Тут ответ с `fractions` будет уместен, а в связанных вопросах - нет.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, начну изучение в этом направлении

Answer (score 8):

Используйте класс [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#module-fractions) (fraction - дробь, внутри число хранится как пара целых чисел (числитель и знаменатель дроби), а не число с плавающей точкой). Пример:

```
# coding: utf-8
from fractions import Fraction

# "Неточный" вариант
print float(8993229949524469768) / 62050608388552823487 * 62050608388552823487
print int(float(8993229949524469768) / 62050608388552823487 * 62050608388552823487)
# Точный вариант через дроби
print Fraction(8993229949524469768, 62050608388552823487) * 62050608388552823487
# Или так
print Fraction(8993229949524469768) / 62050608388552823487 * 62050608388552823487
```

Результат:

```
8.99322994952e+18
8993229949524470784
8993229949524469768
8993229949524469768
```

Тут нужно заметить, что даже просто при преобразовании числа 8993229949524469760 в число с плавающей точкой теряется точность:

```
print int(float(8993229949524469768))
# Выведет 8993229949524469760
```

Дело в том, что хотя число попадает в диапазон значений чисел с плавающей точкой, но выходит за диапазон возможных значений мантиссы и фактический диапазон целых чисел, которые можно хранить в виде числа с плавающей точкой: от `- 2 ** 53` до `+ 2 ** 53`, т.е. от -9007199254740992 до 9007199254740992 (см. [Precision limitations on integer values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values))  - из-за этого данное число нельзя точно представить в виде числа с плавающей точкой.

---

По поводу вот этого:

> Если делить целое на целое, то получим целое. В данном случае a/b= 0. Значит либо одно из чисел, прописав в переменные, задать дробным форматом a= 1.0 или дать тип данных a=float(89....)

Можно сделать импорт  `from __future__ import division`, тогда деление целого на целое будет давать число с плавающей точкой (как в Python 3):

```
from __future__ import division

print 8993229949524469768 / 62050608388552823487
```

Результат: 0.144933791675